# A Problem with using DataFrame.sort_values with information from tkinter entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
import collections
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import time
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table,TableModel
from datetime import datetime
criteria_name=['Pick Rate','Win rate','Tie rate','On Fire']
def get_hero_data(s):
  names = [a for i, [_, a] in enumerate(re.findall('/heroes/(.*?)">(.*?)</a>', s)) if i%2 != 0]
  numbers = re.findall("<span>(.*?)%</span>", s)
  final_numbers = [[re.findall('[\d\.]+$', a)[0], b, c, d] for a, b, c, d in [numbers[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(numbers), 4)]]
  return [[a]+b for a, b in zip(names, final_numbers)]

def data_sort(s):
  role=str(role_entry.get())
  criteria=str(crit_entry.get())
  csv_ornot=str(csv_entry.get())
  role_list=[]
  for i in range(0,len(s)):
    if s.loc[i]['Role']==role and role!='All':
      role_list.append(df.loc[i])
    elif role=='All':
      role_list.append(df.loc[i])
  role_df=pd.DataFrame(role_list, columns=['Hero','Pick Rate','Win rate','Tie rate','On Fire','Role'])
  role_df.sort_values(by=criteria,ascending=False,inplace=True)
  if csv_ornot=='t' or csv_ornot== 'T':
    now=datetime.now()
    role_df.to_csv(str(now.year)+str(now.month)+str(now.day)+str(now.hour)+str(now.minute)+' Overbuff.csv')
  pt=Table(frame,dataframe=role_df)
  pt.show()

window=Tk()
frame=Frame(window)
frame.pack()
hero_listing = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.overbuff.com/heroes')
this_week_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]')
this_week_box.click()
time.sleep(2)
grand_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[8]')
grand_box.click()
time.sleep(2)
hero_listing = get_hero_data(driver.page_source)
df=pd.DataFrame(hero_listing, columns=['Hero','Pick Rate','Win rate','Tie rate','On Fire'])
df['Role']='0'
tank_name=['Sigma','Wrecking Ball','Zarya','Reinhardt','Orisa','D.Va','Winston','Roadhog']
heal_name=['Zenyatta','Baptiste','Mercy','Moira','Lúcio','Ana','Brigitte']   
for i in range(0,len(df)):
  if df.loc[i]['Hero'] in tank_name:
    df.loc[i]['Role']='Tanker'
  elif df.loc[i]['Hero'] in heal_name:
    df.loc[i]['Role']='Healer'
  else:
    df.loc[i]['Role']='DPS'
label=Label(window, text="데이터 기준은 이번 주 그랜드마스터 구간입니다")
label.pack()
role_label=Label(window, text='역할(DPS/Tanker/Healer/All) 입력')
role_label.pack()
role_entry=Entry(window,text='역할',width=50)
role_entry.pack()
crit_label=Label(window,text='정렬 기준(Pick Rate, Win rate, Tie rate, On Fire, Role) 입력')
crit_label.pack()
crit_entry=Entry(window,text='정렬 기준',width=50)
crit_entry.pack()
csv_label=Label(window,text='csv로 저장하시겠습니까? y/n_')
csv_label.pack()
csv_entry=Entry(window,text='y/n',width=50)
csv_entry.pack()
do_button=Button(window,text='작동',command=data_sort(df))
do_button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

and error: File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1563, in _get_label_or_level_values
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: ''

Nothing was wrong until I decided to use GUI interface.
This means that the problem came from "reading and setting a criteria for sorting values" from "Entry"
How can i fix this?

Comment: The root of the problem is here: `command=data_sort(df)`. For an explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Comment: `command=` needs function's name without `()` and arguments. If you have to use with argument then you can use `lambda` to create function with arguments - `command=lambda:data_sort(df)` and will works similar to `def myfunc(): data_sort(df)` and `command=myfunc`

Comment: always put full error message (tarting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There ar other useful infomation.